# How to set two floated divs to be the 100% height of the page

Tags: css, html, css-float

There are two floated divs of different height inside a wrapper div. I need both of them to be 100% of height of the body i.e. of the same height. Also used clearfix. But `height:100%` doesnt seem to work. How to do this?

[Demo](http://jsbin.com/iQuxomUj/2/)

Html:

```
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="primary">
                <img src="http://demo1.opentaps.org/images/products/small/gis_computer_glen_rolla.png" />
            </div>
            <div class="secondary">
                <img src="http://demo1.opentaps.org/images/products/small/gis_computer_glen_rolla.png" />
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix">

            </div>
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    min-height: 100vh;
    background-color: green;
    margin: 0;
}

.wrapper{
    background-color: blue;
  height: 100%;
}

.primary{
    float: left;
    width: 80%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: yellow;
}

.primary img{
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}

.secondary{
    float: right;
    width: 20%;
    background-color: red;
  height: 100%;
}

.secondary img{
    height: 500px;
    width: 100px;
}

.clearfix{
    clear: both;
}
```

Comment: check http://jsbin.com/UzOjUPiL/2 this one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to use vh units (seen in your code), it does makes it easier, no need to worry about 'heritage' and see your columns being stopped at 100% height of the window.

if you mix the method of faux-column and clear fix , you need to set only once min-height:100vh; on the floatting element.

Your yellow background has to be drawn in the wrapper and the red one in the non-floatting element wich is stretch with the clearfix method.

```
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.wrapper{
  background-color: yellow;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.primary{
  float: left;
  width: 80%;  
  min-height:100vh;
}
.wrapper .primary img{
  height: 100px;
  /* width:1000px; */
  width: 100px;
}

.secondary .overflow{
  margin-left:80%;
  background-color: red;
}
.overflow:after {
  content:'';
  height:0;
  display:block;
  clear:both;
}
.secondary img{
  height: 500px;
  /*height:100px;*/
  width: 100px;
}
```

uncomment height value for image to check behavior and drawing of your page, scrolling or not .
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/chHtK

Hope this helps you to understand the use of vh (or vw) units , for the faux-column and clearfix methods, it's just a reminder of old methods  :)

Enjoy

Comment: My regrets, its working fine now. That was a little problem with codepen itself I think. I needed to resize the output window to see it in action.

Comment: I want to achieve a layout like this ( https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/77212526/layout.jpg ). Can I do this using faux-columns?

Comment: I believe you could, with a background image as image or linear-gradient, (no need for regrets, it's fine :) )

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is add a height of 100% to the html and body tags like so:

```
html, body {
   height: 100%;
}
```

Demo:

http://jsbin.com/EsOfABAL/1/

Comment: if page has a scroll, red and yellow backgrounds are broken :)

Comment: I tried it, but this method fails when one of the columns is larger in height than the viewport.

Answer (score 0):

The html element also needs to be 100% - try this:

```
html { height: 100%; }
body {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: green;
    margin: 0;
}
```